# Translating: "Know and understand this king. Be sure that you make yourself a disciple of Christ the ruling King."

Tags: motto, english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to write a motto and my knowledge of Latin is not very profound.

I wish to state using Latin to the effect of, and using king rather than man:

> Know and understand this king. Be sure that you make yourself a disciple of Christ the ruling King.

To know and understand is suggested to be as grok. I do not wish to over complicate.

The best arrangement that I have so far come up with is,

> Intellegere et scire regem. Fac tu discipulis Christi Regis

Is this anything near close? What would be correct Latin?

I do hope that this question will be allowed.

#### Edit

Having studied the magnificent answer from Ethan Bierlein and elsewhere I have near settled that the motto will be as follows:

> Scītō atque intellege hunc rēgem. Es certus facere tē discipulum Christī Regēntis.

Answers yet improving upon this will be considered.

Comment: The first sentence has two very different readings, depending on whether you omitted a comma. Do you mean that the king needs to know and understand ("know and understand this, king"), or that the listener needs to know and understand the king?

Comment: @brianpck I intend for this motto that the reader is told to know and understand this king who is the bearer of the motto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence in your translation is somewhat on-track, you simply neglected to insert the first person demonstrative adjective (*hic, haec, hoc*) for *rēgem* and used infinitive forms instead of imperative forms. The second sentence, however, is not terribly on-track (i.e, improper use of an imperative, incorrect indirect discourse, an incorrectly declined noun, etc.).

If you care less for a more pragmatic translation, I might suggest the following two sentences. If you are addressing a singular person:

> *Scītō atque intellege hunc rēgem. Es certus facere tē discipulum Christī, regentis rēgis.*

If you are addressing a singular person, and that person is female, then *certus* and *discipulum* should become *certa* and *discipulam*, respectively.

If you are addressing multiple people.

> *Scītōte atque intellegite hunc rēgem. Este certī facere vōs discipulōs Christī, regentis rēgis.*

If you mistyped in your original question, and meant to type *"know and understand this, king"* instead of *"know and understand this king"*, then *rēgem* should be in its vocative form, *rēx*. A feminine or plural sentence would then be unnecessary, thus making your full sentence:

> *Scītō atque intellege hoc, rēx. Es certus facere tē discipulum Christī, regentis rēgis.*

Comment: Your magnificent translation easily shows just how bad Google Translate truely is. I take point, however, that the motto intends to say Christ who is the actively ruling King rather than is ruling the king.

Answer (score 1):

For the opening words a C10 hagiography copied into [Harley 2253 f132v ch.5](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=harley_ms_2253_f132v) keeps "*Rex*" in the nominative/vocative, which seems better than *regem,* Accusative:
"King, recognise and understand:"

> Rex accippe et intellige

[image: Rex accippe et intellige in 13th C. handwriting]
and the King is promised a throne at the heavenly banquet.